# React setState not rendering view of bootstrap table

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-modal

I have this component that has a Bootstrap Table and a Modal. User should be able to go into the modal and change the state of the same data for both the table and the modal; however, I am seeing that it is only changing the view in the modal but not the table?

**Component with Table and Modal:**

```
export class TableAndModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data,
            showModal: false,
            index: ""
            }
        };
        this.setShow = this.setShow.bind(this);
        this.handleShowAndChange = this.handleShowAndChange.bind(this);
    }

    columns = [{
        dataField: "view",
        text: "View"
        formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button variant="info" onClick={() => this.setShow(rowIndex)}>View</Button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }, 
      {dataField: 'fullName', text: 'Full Name' }, 
      {dataField: 'studentDesc', text: 'Student Description'}, 
      {dataField: 'email', text: 'Email'}, 
      {dataField: 'fullNotes', text: 'Full Notes'}, 
      {dataField: 'edu', text: 'Education'}, 
      {dataField: 'phone', text: 'Phone Number'}, 
      {dataField: 'id', text: 'ID'}];

    setShow(index) {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
            index: index
        });
    }

    handleShowAndChange = (name, value) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            let newState = {...prevState};
            newState[name] = value;
            return newState;
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BootstrapTable
                    hover
                    condensed={true}
                    bootstrap4={true}
                    keyField={'id'}
                    data={this.state.data.info}
                    columns={this.columns}
                />
                <Modal data={this.state.data.info} index={this.state.index}
                                     showModal={this.state.showModal} onChange={this.handleShowAndChange} />
            </div>


        );

    }
}
```

**Modal:**

```
this.state = {
    data: this.props.data
   };

handleInfoChange = (index) => (name, value) => {
    let info = this.state.data.info.slice();
    info[index][name] = value;
    this.props.onChange("info", info);

};
```

I am seeing that the state is being modified correctly. However, the table still has the same view with the old state data even though the state has been changed.

Can someone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you handling the data props in `BootstrapTable` table component correctly? You might be missing internal state update logic for the `BootstrapTable` table using `componentwillreceiveprops` or something similar.

Comment: @Anshul I am currently not, because I thought if the state is changed; it would re-render the components with the new state. Does it not?

Comment: None of `<BootstrapTable/>` props changed - no reason to rerender or ... renders the same state - reconcilation - no DOM update

Comment: @xadm Is it possible to change props inside the BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next' ?? Shouldn't the props change when the state changed data={this.state.data.info}?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `props.data` instead of `this.props.data`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     data: props.data,
     showModal: false,
     index: ""
  }
}
```